# How to get Full path URl using Gorouter for deep linking Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

How to  find a way of getting full path through go_router? My app support multiple sub domains and I need to know which one was called.

*.domain.com/path

GoRouterState provide me details only for path and nothing for domain or sub domain. How can I get it?

Comment: any updates on this one ? I also need to know the domain/baseUrl of the deeplink